# Unable to knit rmd file in R studio. Receiving error that there is no "lmSupport" package but I am not loading in this package

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit an .rmd file to pdf.  I am receiving the following error message:

```
Error in library(lmSupport) : there is no package called ‘lmSupport’
Execution halted
```

lmsupport is not in my code at all. I tried restarting R and clearing cache. Not sure what else to do.

I have the most recent version of R downloaded on my Mac

Comment: @KJ I'm not sure how that would help, given that the issue is not that she's trying to call a package she doesn't have installed.

Comment: @MichelleM it is possible that while you don't call on that package, there is a package you are calling that depends on it. It is no longer available on CRAN, but you can download the archived version and install it locally, than try again: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lmSupport/

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your comment. Yes, it turns out I need that package for a different package. I tried downloading the archived version and am now getting this error: installation of package lmSupport_2.9.13.tar’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: It's difficult to help without further information. What was the line of code that was run when you tried to install it? What is the full output of the attempt? Please edit your question with that information.

Comment: @Phil I ended up taking out all code that references lmsupport and I am getting the same error when I try to knit.

Comment: If you are using a package that depends on it, or if you have `library(lmSupport)`, the error will remain. But you should be able to download the archived tar files and install locally.